# How can I type a degree symbol (0176) from my Surface RT Touch keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, microsoft-surface

I have a Microsoft Surface RT with a Touch keyboard.  I regularly need to type a degrees symbol.  On a full keyboard, I can use the code (0176) with the numeric keypad.  But the Touch keyboard doesn't have a numeric keypad.  Is there any way to type a degrees symbol without resorting to the Character Map or on-screen keyboard?

Comment: Why don't you want to resort to the on-screen keyboard? (And the title didn't explain that -- hence Big Chris' answer, I assume.)

Comment: "Touch keyboard" means the on-screen keyboard. Thus, in your question, you're contradicting yourself. Do you mean the Touch Cover?

Answer (score 2):

It appears this cannot be done using the Surface keyboards. You can use the on-screen keyboard or connect a standard USB keyboard and use the "Alt + code" (you must only use the number keypad to the side of your keyboard, however)

On-screen keyboard instructions:

1. Bring up the on-screen keyboard
2. Press "&123"
3. Press the arrow key in a circle to the left of the keyboard
4. The "degree" symbol is on one of the pages

Note: Pressing and holding the "degree" symbol shows a slightly larger symbol if needed.

I've absolutely no idea if you can type using the previous "Alt + number"... I have left feedback on the Microsoft feedback page for the keyboard instruction page for Surface.

Comment: ...but isn't this the on-screen keyboard, for which the question says *"without resorting to the Character Map or on-screen keyboard*"? That said, I feel that's an unreasonable addition given the question's title, so +1 anyway ;-) (Also, as I'm quite sure Alt-codes are not supported, but I could be wrong.)

Comment: Whoops! It would really help if I read the rest of the question... I assumed the "touch keyboard" was referring to the on-screen... what a tool. Sorry! I think you're right, however, as I have one of the cover/keyboards (not "touch", but clicky keys) and the "Alt + code" doesn't work at all. Not even a USB keyboard plugged in. Pressing "Alt" starts opening menus and displaying accessibility keys.

Comment: I've done some further testing and if you use a standard USB keyboard you **can** do "Alt + code" but (as MS say) you have to use the number keypad (not the numbers at the top of the keyboard)

Comment: No worries, if the question is really about entering Alt-codes, it should have said so, and not only mention the specific example of that degrees symbol... As an aside: I've seen that even a mouse works with those tablets. :-)

Comment: Ah, maybe the question is even about a hardware keyboard, the Touch Cover. I didn't even realize that. Messy question, but it even made it to the Super User Twitter feed.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

1. Go to On-Screen Keyboard
2. Then hit the OPTIONS BUTTON [RIGHT at the BOTTOM OF THE SCREEN BETWEEN ON THE KEYBOARD ITSELF and Check the box [Turn on Numeric Key Pad]
3. Hit NumLock
4. Type now your Alt Character using the Numeric Key Pad

Answer (score 1):

1. Pres and hold Windows button (one with window) then pres R.
2. Type OSK. pres enter.
3. Click options on the onscreen keyboard (OSK).
4. Click turn on "numeric key pad" so that there is a tick.
5. Click OK.
6. on the bottom
7. right-hand corner you will see "NumLock".

Comment: If you can't see numlock on the bottom right, click options and you will have a checkbox. Thanks for this. I have a typecover and it doesn't have all the options and the 'onscreen keyboard' button doesn't give you the full OSK that this option does.

Answer (score 1):

If trying to do it in MS Word (and maybe Excel and PowerPoint, although I didn't try) you can use the Type Cover and hit Cntl-Shift 2, let go and hit the space bar.

It's assigned to Cntl@ then space but that @ sign is really Shift 2 cause it's above the #2 on the top row.

For any symbol, you can go to the Character Map (swipe in from right, hit Search and start to type Character Map) and then look up the symbol you want. Then click on the bottom where it says Shortcut Key and it may already be assigned to one (the one I wanted was the Euro symbol and I found out that it's already assigned to Alt-Cntl-E). If not already assigned, you can assign it although you want to make sure the combo of keys you choose are not already doing something else you want.

My only issue now is, because there's no number keypad and I can't get the Alt combo to work even with the On Screen Keyboard or num pad on one of the touch keyboards, I can't use the Alt combo in this other software I'm using. But I did find my Euro by clicking on the touch screen icon in lower right corner, click on &123, then forward arrow and there's the Euro symbol. So for MS Word you are all set for your degree symbol. Other stuff, I can't say. My Euro shortcut doesn't work in the other software cause the other software is already using that combo for another function.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a Surface Pro 3 with the Surface keyboard set to US language.

I can type the euro symbol using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>.

This works for most Windows applications including Outlook and Word.

Comment: OP is asking about degree symbol

Answer (score -1):

If you're talking about the Surface Touch Cover, I haven't found a way. I own a Surface Pro and I can't type a degree symbol with my Type Cover. Best off using the on-screen keyboard.